# Spring BeanUtil.copyProperties not work for record

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-17

BeanUtils.copyProperties is failing while copy a record

```java
public record ServiceCodeAndNameDomain(String serviceCode, String serviceName) {}
```

Exception

```java
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: xxx.ServiceCodeAndNameDomain.<init>()
```

Environment
jdk: 17.0.1
springboot: 2.6.6

I know that copyProperties is dependent on no argument constructor, but in record, it must be all arguments constructor

Can anyone tell me what is the best practice in such case?

Comment: "I know that copyProperties is dependent on no argument constructor" - and exactly that is why it does not work for records, because records do not have a no-args constructor.

Comment: Is manual copyProperties the only way left for record type?

Comment: even if you provided a no-argument constructor (with default values for fields), record classes are meant to be immutable (fields cannot be changed). You may provide a copy-constructor, that is, one that receives an instance and creates a new one copying the fields... (not sure if that functionality is really needed for records, why not use the same one?)

Comment: @user16320675 he might want to copy properties from an object of a different type that has fields with the same names. You would indeed not need a copy constructor that makes an exact copy of a record, because records are (supposed to be) immutable, so you could safely reuse an existing instance.

Comment: When there are many argument, using constructor copy makes the code unattractive. So I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do argument copying

Comment: @Jesper I already wrote that records are immutable and that it is not clear why they would need to copy it... the copy-constructor can easily be adapted to receive an instance of a different class (OK, maybe it should not be called copy-constructor in such case, but I don't know a better name).

Comment: Although tempting to use `BeanUtils.copyProperties` the javadoc also warns that this is mainly for internal framework use. For mapping from objects to other objects use a proper mapping framework like MapStruct.

Comment: @user16320675 there are cases when it kind of makes sense for such copy constructors to be provided (somehow I wish by javac). Think of a case where a record has many fields, while you want to create a copy, changing only a single field. The code inside the record becomes so cluttered, that simple setters are a much better fit. So boilerplate for more boilerplate. I, personally, wish some sort of copy constructors would be provided - but I do understand it would make no sense in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @Eugene agreed, but as I already wrote, more than once, "records are immutable" (or at least supposed to be)

Comment: @user16320675 my comment has nothing to do with mutability.

Comment: @Eugene OK "*simple setters are a much better fit*"¹ for a immutable class ?? The components of a Record Class are `final` and you are not allowed to add non-`static` fields to it (AFAIK) - no great advantage to have a setter... (**¹** from your comment) I agree that copy-constructor would eventually be useful, but not for Record Classes (as of now)

Comment: @user16320675 ah! I see, I mean "plain class that supports setters, unlike records". And yes, non-static fields are not allowed, neither is inheritance that might cause this.

Comment: @Eugene sorry, I don't remember all the details (my comments are more than 6 months old now !?!) but the question is about a record class and so are my comments (clearly(?) stated in both) - so I do not understand what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With reference to @user16320675 comments, I considered providing cross-type properties copies in the following way

```java
public record ServiceCodeAndNameDomain(String serviceCode, String serviceName) {

    public static ServiceCodeAndNameDomain of(ServiceRegistry entity){
        return new ServiceCodeAndNameDomain(entity.getServiceCode(),entity.getServiceName());
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a better practice

Comment: What is the benefit of creating another identical record? Why not pass the original everywhere as it is immutable. If you wanted to copy properties to another record type with a superset of properties, you could use Jackson ObjectMapper. convertValue()